# Create a template and replace placeholders dynamically in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, liquid

I have a set template in which there is address informations and other set of user information.

I have created a html file in the public folder and load the file at runtime and use

```
template = File.read("public/filename.html")
template % {key:value}
```

to replace the tokens with actual value and process as required.

Can anyone please let me know if its the correct way to do this, or are there any better ways like placing the template in other folders like views, bin etc?

Comment: huh? Why dont you use rails' templates with `render`?

Comment: I have to generate a PDF with user information and have to save that as a template file for further editing by admin. Thats the reason i have kept it as a template file

Answer (score 1):

I would use [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf). After you've installed it, create a new route and controller that will take your user/address info as params and pass them as an instance variable into your template. From there, you can can template the pdf just like a regular view.

Comment: I am using wicked pdf. but what i want to know is whats the best way to code in a scenario where there is template file which i load and substitute tokens

Answer (score -1):

```
vim app/view/filename.html.erb
```

you can create template(view) and set the root to

```
config/routes
```